# Why is PHPUnit in Hudson CI using my localhost path AND my actual filepath?

Tags: php, unit-testing, continuous-integration, hudson, phpunit

**EDIT 3:** ***Solved.*** See below.

**EDIT 2:** I think Chadwick's on the right track with his comment. **Hudson/PHPUnit is taking the localhost (the Hudson workspace) AND my local file structure and using both to run the unit tests.** So it's redeclaring everything that was already declared. Why is this happening and how can I change it?

I've since [reported this issue on Hudson's JIRA Server](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-6947). If I get a resolution there, I'll post here. Otherwise, any help would be appreciated since my builds are going nowhere now.

My build keeps failing and I can't for the life of me understand why. Here's what I get back.

```
phpunit:
[exec] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare generate_options() (previously declared in
<http://localhost:8080/job/Goals/ws/Goals/includes/functions/registration_fns.php>:5) in /Users
/joshsmith/Sites/Goals/Goals/includes/functions/registration_fns.php on line 32
```

But this particular function starts at line 5 and ends at line 32! So what in the world is going on here?

And just so you know PHPUnit works on its own outside of Hudson. Here's my terminal output from a successful test run:

```
Macintosh:goals joshsmith$ phpunit alltests.class
PHPUnit 3.4.14 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.............................

Time: 14 seconds, Memory: 9.75Mb

OK (29 tests, 67 assertions)
```

Can anyone help me figure this craziness out?

**EDIT:** Under Chadwick's suggestion, I tried renaming the function in case it were trying to redeclare a function internal to Hudson. This didn't work, and is clearly some other obscure issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved. It was an issue where I had hardcoded the paths in a single initializer file. As a result, they were being redeclared by PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `generate_options()` is declared both in your `registration_fns.php` file and in some file by Hudson. PHP function names are global, so this is an inherent risk of combining code from a third party.

One way around it is to rename one of the functions (and of course all calls to it) - you can modify the Hudson code where it is declared, or modify your own, but personally I recommend changing your own. Should you upgrade Hudson in the future, you'd likely have to modify it again.

Since PHP 5.3, you also have the option of using [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think this is the issue because I just went back through and renamed the generate_options() function and it's still giving me the redeclare error. What's bizarre is that it says it's being redeclared on line 32 when declared on line 5.

Comment: interestingly, it shows the two files that conflict, one is an http url, the other being a file. Is your Hudson config somehow reading files from both the web version and your local file system? Might it be the same file conflicting with itself because it is being read twice?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't really noticed that. How can I go about changing that path? I'm a complete Hudson n00b so appreciate your patience and help.

Comment: I've never used HudsonPHP, but have fought the redeclare error firsthand. My last comment is only a guess - all I can say is it looks like the same file is being included twice through different means. Best of luck!

Comment: Chadwick, from the way you were talking I figured that was the case. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, though. Never hurts to have a second set of eyes. I've edited my question and question title to reflect your suggestions. Thanks!